blazor serverside oidc how to logout?
i have some blazor serverside app that uses our corporate oidc
so startup i have:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.Authority = "https://xx.yy.xx/dev";
    options.ClientId = "Dev";
    options.ClientSecret = "Secreeeet";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.Scope.Remove("profile");
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "name"
    };
    options.SignOutScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});

and this simply works... redirrets to login page / redirrects back etc. OK
and now i need to have some 'logout' button
how should i write this logout method?
this is not webassembly so there is no 'redirret to login/ logout' etc methods
so how should this logout be handled?
Thanks and regards;

You could try call await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); for logout.

hi thanks but this is blazor serverside / are You shure that this should work? / i get Error CS0117 'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'SignOutAsync'

In your razor component you can use the following
  <button href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut">
     Logout
  </button>

Blazor server will automatically map this with your domain and attach this at the end. This will take you the logout session and the user has to click logout. In your program.cs add the following:
app.UseRewriter(
    new RewriteOptions().Add(
        context =>
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path == "/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignedOut")
                context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/");
        }));

This will return the user to the home page of your application. Otherwise, the application will only say logout success and will not return to your website.

hello thanks but no this does not work / im not using microsoft identity / as You may see i use oidc external

There are 2 levels logout for oidc, signout "cookie" scheme is for this app. signout "oidc" will logout the session in identity server which signout all sso websites.
This process need to be done with httpcontext. Just create a button and navigate (forcereload) to this custom "/signout" path will make httpcontext available.
app.MapGet("/signout" , async (httpContext)=>
{
    await httpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    await httpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
});

-----------------------------update----------------
Get token and add to token_hint
            options.SaveTokens = true;

            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
            {
                OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async arg =>
                {
                   var token = await arg.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("oidc", "id_token");
                   arg.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = token;  
                }
            };


thanks this is close but when i click then i get from this oidc - key message that 'Missing parameters: id_token_hint; - what is that? / how to pass this?

@Dorian I didn't reproduce this error with code flow. But you may add the tokenhint in the OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut event. I have update the answer you could have a try. The token_hint is to recognize which user to signout.

still close but no :( it throws that no oidc auth scheme is registered , i changed to
var token = await arg.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("OpenIdConnect", "id_token"); OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken
or var token = await arg.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken);
but token is null in both cases

maybe because await httpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); is called firstly so this token do not exists anymore?
